# Freemember - logout doesn't keep https protocol

Tags: freemember

I have a https section of my site I am using with Freemember.  But when I logout it takes me to the http version.  How can I make it logout but stay https?

```
<a href="{exp:freemember:logout_url return='"{current_path}"'}" >Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this issue with a number of tags and modules, you can use a module like : https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/https-support to alter the base `site_index` variable globally according to the protocol being used. No need to alter 3rd party code...

Comment: Amazing find! This instantly fixed the issue with Freemember Forgot Password forms not working, and removed the mixed content warning from the EE Simple Search too.

Answer (score 0):

In the mod.freemember.php

After the following code (line 221):

```
$url = ee()->functions->fetch_site_index().QUERY_MARKER.
        'ACT='.ee()->functions->fetch_action_id(__CLASS__, 'act_logout');
```

Add the following code:

```
if (ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('secure_action') == 'yes') {  
        $url = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $url);  
    }
```

This will change the logout url to https. You have to add secure_action to logout url as follows:

```
{exp:freemember:logout_url return="" secure_action="yes"}
```